Why B737 CFM56 engine sounds like heavy wind sound at Throttling up?



14:14 ~ 14:21 : Throttle Up (with heavy wind sound
14:22 ~ 14:23 : Engine reached certain %, and no heavy wind sound
14:23 ~ : Throttle Up (with heavy wind sound)
I always wonder why only B737NG with CFM56 Engine sounds with heavy wind sound when they throttling up. Once the engine reaches a certain percentage, the wind sound disappears, but is this simply because of the sudden suction of air due to throttle up? or is there another reason?

This is a great question! I hadn't noticed that before. I've checked a few other 737NG takeoff videos, and it seems like if you are sitting near the exhaust (not intake) you can definitely hear this. I wonder if it may have something to do with how the FADEC spools the engine when the TO/GA buttons are pressed on the throttle. If you watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ve89DuLFwY at 5:37 you can see the 1st officer click those buttons, and the lever advance then pauses for a second at 5:41...? The timings seem close to the ones in your video

@AlastairWyllie "lever advance then pauses for a second at 5:41" That is the SOP, also when not using the AT. You always let N1 stabilize at around 80% to make sure thrust is symmetric and let both engines spool at the same time.

@DeepSpace - From what I understand often one engine will inherently spool faster than the other, and the symmetric thrust can be problematic if going straight from idle to 100%. By holding at 80% you let the slower engine "catch up", and then while there will be some asymmetry going from 80 to100% it's not enough to create a problem.

Not 80%, but 40% N1. Get both N1s stabilized at 40%, then click TOGA and let the AT advance power to the computed takeoff thrust. The TOGA function itself has no such pause built in.
